# Generic Methods that overwrite parameters without reference?

Tags: c#, ref

Okay this might be a really stupid quesion but I will risk my rep anyway. I'm pretty new to programming so take it easy will ya ;)
So I just got into TCP when I encountered something I dont quite understand.
To be specific:

```
int length = Socket.Receive(MyByteArray);
```

To my understanding this method returns the length of the data beeing received **and** writes the recieved data into my byte array. So how does it write into my byte array without me telling it to? After some research I learned that you can use references to do this kind of thing but this method doesn't require "ref MyByteArray" which leaves me puzzled. Is this a different kind of Method or is it what is going on inside the method (duh)?

Thanks in advance you utterly awesome person.

Comment: Do some research on reference types and value types.  Arrays are reference types, so when you pass one to a function it has a _reference_ to the actual object and can change its properties.

Comment: You are telling it to write into your byte array by passing your byte array into it.

Comment: Without explaining _why_, it's easy to verify by yourself _that_ it works: http://ideone.com/HrLDZ3

Comment: Read this carefully http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Arrays are reference types, not value types (even though its an array of value types), so if the array is pre-allocated it doesn't need to be passed with `ref`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a *reference type* into a method can sometimes be an unintuitive thing for developers.  Consider these two pieces of code (neither of which use the `ref` keyword):

```
void Method1(SomeType myObj)
{
    myObj = new SomeType();
}

void Method2(SomeType myObj)
{
    myObj.SomeProperty = 1;
}
```

The first method has no side effects.  The reference type was passed into the method, which for lack of a better term is basically a "pointer" (itself passed by value) to the object in memory.  If you set the variable to a *new* object in memory, the original remains unchanged.  There are then two objects in memory.  (Though the new one will go away once the method ends, because nothing uses it.)

The *second* method, however, *does* have a side-effect.  It uses the same reference to the object in memory, but it modifies the object itself.  So anything which examines the object after the method is called will see that modification.

---

Presumably, `Socket.Receive()` does something similar to the second method above.  It uses the reference to modify the object.

---

To illustrate how the `ref` keyword would change this:

```
void Method3(ref SomeType myObj)
{
    myObj = new SomeType();
}
```

In *this* scenario, there is also a side-effect.  Any code which calls the method and then, afterward, examines the object it sent to the method will then see that the object has been replaced with a new one.  In this case there wasn't a second "pointer" to the same location in memory.  The method used the actual *pointer* that the calling code used.

Comment: For clarity, why wouldn't you use just always use ref when you're modifying the original object?

Comment: @ThatBrianDude: I suppose you *could*.  To be honest, methods like `Socket.Receive()` kind of bother me in that regard.  I personally find it *unexpected* for something I pass to a method to be modified.  Following the Principle of Least Astonishment and whatnot.  For any given method in the framework where this happens, I suspect there is a history of where it came from and why they did that and now it is what it is and they can't introduce a breaking change.  But anything we write today really shouldn't modify the object like that.

Comment: @David you have to understand where an array originates, it inherits from `class Array`. That being said, a class will be passed by reference ;) . Consider this a C++ pointer, and it makes sense to pass the reference to the array where the data will be written...

Comment: @PhilippeParé: Did you mean to send that comment to the other user?  I'm fairly familiar with reference types...

Comment: @David no, I was talking about what you said: "To be honest, methods like Socket.Receive() kind of bother me in that regard. I personally find it unexpected for something I pass to a method to be modified.", I find it quite logical if you think of the array as the `byte*` that it represents

Comment: @PhilippeParé: I was referring to a matter of personal preference.  I'm fully aware of how reference types work.  The point I was making is that passing something to a method and having that something be mutated (at least without the `ref` keyword) is, in my opinion, unintuitive.  I understand the technical reasons of *how* this is accomplished.  I just don't think it's a good design choice.  The code reads less cleanly and it forces the developer to stop his train of thought for a moment and think about something else.  Regardless of how simple that something else is, it breaks concentration.